# React router not going to not found page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a header that I want to display on some pages. So I wrapped the pages I want it on around a `<></>` and that worked. But the NotFound page is now never showing up and the header sits there on an empty page and **not** on the not found page. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
            <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}></Route>

            <>
                <Header />
                <Route path='/cool-page' component={Cool}></Route>
                <Route path='/another-page' component={Another}></Route>

                <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Redirect to='/cool-page'></Redirect>}></Route>
            </>

            // This never get called...
            <Route path='/' component={NotFound}></Route>
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two routes matching `'/'`. Change it to `'/*'` to match all wild card routes.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to remove the `path` attribute alltogether

Comment: probably a stupid question but nevertheless: does the `NotFound` component render any thing?

Comment: Not a stupid question !!! :) Yes, it does. It works correclty when I don't have the sidbar and <></>

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, sorry :/ Maybe you could set up a simple react stackblitz. then I could take a closer look

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it in the docs but my feeling is (and I tested it on my own) that the `<></>` in your switch always evaluates as true so it never reaches the `NotFound` Route, my suggestion is to try put the catch all for the `NotFound` component inside the `<>...</>

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}></Route>

    <>
        <Header />
        <Route path='/cool-page' component={Cool}></Route>
        <Route path='/another-page' component={Another}></Route>

        <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Redirect to='/cool-page'></Redirect>}></Route>
        <Route path='/*' component={NotFound}></Route>
    </>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not reaching the end of route because of the `<></>`. Instead of react fragment `<></>` try a component and another switch on it. I tried some combinations and this one works:

```
const WithHeader = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Header</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={() => "Login"}></Route>
    <Route path="/signup" component={() => "Sign Up"}></Route>
    <Route path="/404" component={() => "Not Found"}></Route>

    <WithHeader>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/cool-page" component={() => "Cool Page"}></Route>
            <Route
                path="/another-page"
                component={() => "Another Page"}
            ></Route>
            <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                component={() => <Redirect to="/cool-page"></Redirect>}
            ></Route>
            <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/404" />} />
        </Switch>
    </WithHeader>
</Switch>
```

See working demo here:

[image: Edit]